# Qt widgets limit exceeded

Tags: linux, qt, user-interface, debugging, gcc

I am using Qt 5.6 . I have created a application which contains many widgets such as labels,Buttons..etc.
Now I added a label in to my gui , But I am not able to access the label (ui->label_name).
While compile the application I am getting below prints.

```
*In file included from mainwindow.cpp:10:0: ui_mainwindow.h: In member function 'void Ui_MainWindow::setupUi(QMainWindow*)': ui_mainwindow.h:853:10: note: variable tracking size limit exceeded with -fvar-tracking-assignments, retrying without
     void setupUi(QMainWindow *MainWindow)*
```

Comment: Wow, how many widgets do you have in there? What system (OS/compiler)? Maybe it's time to break up that massive UI into separate parts... ;-) Not sure anyone here can fix that. Did a google search on that warning and it seems legit and you'll need to break up that `setupUi` function (which is auto-generated, so if you're using Designer the only way is to break up the UI into separate widgets/ui files).  And welcome to SO!

Comment: ***But I am not able to access the label*** What does that mean? Is this a debugging issue?

Comment: Hi drescherjm,I have created a label with name labelStatus.But if I give ui->labelStatus it is not taking

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04 as host PC, Qt creator version 4.0.2 and Qt version 5.6. Total 818 widgets are there in my application(Including Buttons,Labels...).

Comment: 800+ manually-created widgets in one design? :-0 That sounds insane. Nothing wrong with being insane, but it can't be efficient to maintain or load. I'd break that up ASAP regardless of what a compiler tells you. Especially considering that the code generated from designer UI files is typically a bit more verbose (does more steps) than strictly required... * 800 that and it becomes code bloat. Makes an interesting .uic file I'm sure.  818... wow...   :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Variable Tracking Assignments](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Var_Tracking_Assignments) is a compiler (GCC) option, oriented to enhance the debugger and optimization experience. If you are experiencing problems while debugging your program, then you may disable optimizations or disable this feature altogether (with the compiler flag '-fno-var-tracking-assignments'). There may be also a bug in your compiler version. If your compiler is too old, you may consider an upgrade. There is no limit for Qt widgets, though.